# Index for each group and subgroup within a group in R

Tags: r, grouping

My dataset consists of two variables. The first variable has 10 unique groups. Within each group, there are variable number of subgroups (the second variable in the dataset). I want to generate an index that will identify the group and each subgroup within that group. For example, if group1 (in my first variable) has 5 subgroups, the indices should be 01-01, 01-02, 01-03, and so on. When the first variable changes to group2, I want the index to increment by 1 - i.e, the indices should now be 02-01, 02-02, and so on.

I haven't been able to come up with a way to accomplish this without getting mired in a maze of for-loops and if statements. My goal is to generalize this to arbitrary number of subgroups within a group (e.g., if there is an additional subgroup within the second subgroup).

EDIT: These are the first 3 rows of my dataset, up to 4 columns. Apologies for not providing this in the original post.

```
structure(list(d1 = c("animal and animal products edible", "animal and animal products edible", 
"animal and animal products edible"), d2 = c("animal edible except for breeding", 
"animal edible except for breeding", "animal edible except for breeding"
), d3 = c("cattle", "cattle", "cattle"), d4 = c("bulls for breeding", 
"cows for breeding", "other cattle")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `dput(df)` would be helpful for people whoever want to help you

Comment: Do you use `dplyr`?

Comment: Yes I do. As well as base R.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated based on example given**

Here, I will coerce the groups in d1 and d2 from character strings to unique indices. Feel free to try with different values to see how it works.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)

DT[, Ind_d1 := as.numeric(as.factor(d1))]
DT[, Ind_d2 := as.numeric(as.factor(d2))]
DT[, Ind_d1_d2 := paste0(Ind_d1, "-", Ind_d2)]
```

You can then create another `data.table` / `data.frame` which lists all the combinations for your reference.

```
DT_Groups <- unique(DT[, .(d1, d2, Ind_d1_d2)])
```

Comment: This code already has preset numbers corresponding to the groups. My groups are character strings. I want each group and subgroups within that group to be numbered. I've attached a snapshot of my data.

Comment: @SaunokChakrabarty Thanks for giving the example in the question. I have updated my answer accordingly. Feel free to let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: It works for the example I provided. But the indexing for the subgroup (d2) doesn't seem to be chronological for my entire dataset. It starts from 1, then goes to 7, 5. I've posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
# indexing first group (d1)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(d1_index = as.integer(factor(d1, levels = unique(d1))))
 
# indexing d2 (the second group) within each d1
df <- df %>%
  group_by(d1) %>% 
  mutate(d2_index = 
           as.integer(factor(d2, levels = unique(d2)))
  )

# padding the indices with leading zeros
df <- df %>%
  mutate(d1_l_index = paste("0", as.character(d1_index), sep = ""))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(d2_l_index = paste("0", as.character(d2_index), sep = ""))

# concatenating the indices
df <- df %>%
  mutate(d1d2_l_index = paste(d1_l_index, d2_l_index, sep = "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you managed to solve your issue. As your sample data weren't enough for a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I've created some for future reference. Also, this is uses more-succinct `tidyverse` code based on your code. Hopefully it'll help show you some other functions that you may not have been aware of:

```
library(dplyr)

# Make this example reproducible
set.seed(1) 
# Create sample df
df <- data.frame(d1 = paste0("group", rep(1:10, each = 10)),
                 d2 = paste0("subgroup", rep(sample.int(5, 20, replace = TRUE))),
                 d3 = "cattle",
                 d4 = sample(c("bulls" ,"cows", "other" ), 100, replace = TRUE))

# Create id variable based on d1 and d2
df1 <- df %>% 
  arrange(d1, d2) %>%
  group_by(d1) %>%
  mutate(xd1 = cur_group_id(),
         xd2 =  cumsum(c(TRUE, d2[-1] != d2[-n()])),
         d1d2_index = paste0("0", xd1, "-", "0", xd2)) %>%
  select(!starts_with("x")) %>%
  ungroup()

print(df1, n = 20)
#     d1        d2      d3    d4   d1d2_index
#   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <chr>     
# 1 group1   subgroup1 cattle bulls 01-01     
# 2 group1   subgroup1 cattle cows  01-01     
# 3 group1   subgroup1 cattle cows  01-01     
# 4 group1   subgroup2 cattle cows  01-02     
# 5 group1   subgroup2 cattle bulls 01-02     
# 6 group1   subgroup3 cattle other 01-03     
# 7 group1   subgroup3 cattle other 01-03     
# 8 group1   subgroup3 cattle cows  01-03     
# 9 group1   subgroup4 cattle cows  01-04     
# 10 group1  subgroup5 cattle bulls 01-05     
# 11 group10 subgroup1 cattle bulls 02-01     
# 12 group10 subgroup1 cattle cows  02-01     
# 13 group10 subgroup1 cattle bulls 02-01     
# 14 group10 subgroup2 cattle other 02-02     
# 15 group10 subgroup2 cattle bulls 02-02     
# 16 group10 subgroup5 cattle cows  02-03     
# 17 group10 subgroup5 cattle other 02-03     
# 18 group10 subgroup5 cattle cows  02-03     
# 19 group10 subgroup5 cattle cows  02-03     
# 20 group10 subgroup5 cattle bulls 02-03
```